# tar-ing / should I use -C / . or just /

Tags: linux, archiving, tar, backup, compression

```
tar cvf backup.tar  -C /  /   # or
tar cvf backup.tar    /
```

produces an archive like

```
etc/
```

and gives warnings

```
tar: Removing leading `/' from member names
tar: Removing leading `/' from hard link targets
```

on the other hand

```
tar cvf backup.tar  -C /  .
```

produces an archive like

```
./etc/
```

and gives no warnings. I got the last one from a Debian tutorial.

Which is best for a system backup, do they work exactly the same?

---

Is there no difference between
tar -tvh producing

> ./etc/

from an archive

and tar -tvh producing

> etc/

from an archive

?

Comment: I don't see that using execve precludes you from using shell commands.  Couldn't execve call /bin/sh with option -c followed by a command line that includes pipes, globs, or whatever else might be needed to create the tar file the way you want?

Comment: Had I been using Unix only, it would have been acceptable. But utility must be portable, and sh doesn't exist on Windows, for example

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Both the examples you give are effectively equivalent - you end up with relative paths in the archive.

If you want to include absolute paths in the archive use -P, but beware that it will be inconvenient to restore to anywhere other than the root.

Comment: Is there no difference between tar -tvh producing

`./etc/`

from an archive

and tar -tvh producing

`etc/`

from an archive

?

Comment: They are different spellings of the same relative path.

Answer (score 0):

What you want to use depends on what you're doing.

If you're just trying to make a backup of your files, then the `tar` command will work for you (more on that below).  If you're trying to make an image of your harddrive, then use the `dd` command.  Please know that you can't just put your `tar` backup on a new drive and boot with it.

The issue you'll run into with the `tar` command is that your file will be placed under the / directory, which is what you're backing up.  So you'll need to exclude your backup file.

`cd /` 
`tar -cvpzf backup.tar.gz --exclude=/backup.tar.gz /`

Comment: I know it won't get the MBR but if I have a /boot partition and I just tarballed the partition the bootloader points to won't that work?  I do the same thing with rsync, works fine.

Comment: That should work if you're planning on restoring your backup to the same drive.  I always plan for the worse (ie, the drive dying).  Has the tar command produced what you were expecting?

Answer (score 0):

I have found a **sed**  solution, it's better than using tar twice.

```
tar cvfz backup.tar.gz -C /path/to/dir/ --transform 's/^\.//' .
```

Comment: Note that this will skip your dotfiles :)